# Simple proof-of-work (based on HashCash)

Tags: java, php, security

I'm trying to build a simple (yet effective) brute-force protection for my App-API.

The client requests an identity - the server supplies a random string (called `seed`, which it remembers via PHP  session) and a security level.

If the client wants to login it needs to supply a suffix for the `seed` which results in a `SHA512` hash with leading zero-bytes (security level times).

**Java (generation):**

```java
import java.security.MessageDigest;
import java.security.NoSuchAlgorithmException;

public class HashCash {
    private final static String HASH_ALGORITHM = "SHA-256";

    private final MessageDigest hashGenerator;

    /**
     * Creates a new HashCash generator using the SHA-256 algorithm
     * @throws NoSuchAlgorithmException If the "SHA-256" algorithm is not available
     */
    public HashCash() throws NoSuchAlgorithmException {
        hashGenerator = MessageDigest.getInstance(HASH_ALGORITHM);
    }

    /**
     * Generates a HashCash for the specified level
     * @param seed A seed for the HashCash
     * @param targetLevel The target level for the HashCash
     * @return The generated HashCash
     */
    public long generateHashCash(final String seed, final int targetLevel) {
        // Variation counter (and final result)
        long counter = 0;
        while(true) {
            // Check if the current hashCash reaches the desired security level
            if(getSecurityLevel(seed + counter) >= targetLevel)
                return counter;
            // Increase hash counter
            counter++;
        }
    }

    /**
     * Computes the security level of the given value
     * @param value The value to compute the level of
     * @return The security level of the value
     */
    private final int getSecurityLevel(final String value) {
        hashGenerator.update(value.getBytes());
        final byte[] hash = hashGenerator.digest();
        int level = 0;
        for(final byte b: hash) {
            if(b != 0)
                break;
            level++;
        }
        return level;
    }
}
```

**PHP (verification):**

```php
const HASH_CASH_SEC_LEVEL = 8;

/**
 * Verifies a HashCash suffix (by checking it's security level)
 * @param string $seed The seed of the identity
 * @param string $suffix The HashCash suffix
 * @return bool Whether the given HashCash suffix is valid
 */
function verifyHashCash(string $seed, string $suffix): bool {
    $hash = hash('sha256', $seed.$suffix, true);
    $level = 0;
    $length = strlen($hash);
    for($b = 0; $b < $length; $b++) {
        if(ord($hash[$b]) !== 0)
            break;
        $level++;
    }
    return $level >= HASH_CASH_SEC_LEVEL;
}
```

- Are there any security related issues?
- Are there performance optimizations for the Java code?

Comment: Do you want to put the `return $level >= HASH_CASH_SEC_LEVEL;` logic into your loop to provide a potential early return?  Then after the loop just return false?

Comment: @mickmackusa It's a possiblity, but I prefer it this way, since i am not concerned with PHP performance and this seems more readable to me. (Plus, on the performence side, the loop usually breaks very early). Thanks anyways!

Comment: So shall we remove the php tag so that php reviewers are not attracted to this page?

Comment: @mickmackusa I am primarily concerned with security, since this is my first proof-of-work implementation. I additionally asked for "performance optimizations for the Java code", since the generating device needs to run these functions a lot (~millions of times), while the verification is a simple check, where I prefer maintainability. I also don't want the client code to be (much) less optimised, than the code of a potential attacker.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
public HashCash() throws NoSuchAlgorithmException {
```

SHA-256 is a requirement for any Java SE environment. Instead of throwing you should be catching and converting to a `RuntimeException` (or `IllegalStateException`) with this particular exception as cause.

```
public long generateHashCash(final String seed, final int targetLevel) {
...
private final int getSecurityLevel(final String value) {
```

If you're going to design for performance you should **not** be using `String` types. The seed should be a byte array from the start. And you could use e.g. `ByteBuffer` to write an integer to an existing array that already starts with the `seed`.

Note that SHA-256 is a Merkle-Damgard hash function that handles input block-by-block. That means that if you start off with a large enough seed (512 bits or larger) you might as well pre-hash it. Of course this means mucking about **within** the hash implementation.

```
if(b != 0)
    break;
level++;
```

Generally the level calculation is performed on bits or even values (where the hash value, when seen as a unsigned number, is below a certain value).

As for performance: you can stop comparing whenever you encounter a number that *doesn't have* the right level. It won't matter much when compared the time required to perform SHA-256 in all probability, but it is still wasteful.

I don't expect `getSecurityLevel` to perform the actual hash calculation. A getter is generally not expected to perform any work at all.

The PHP code doesn't seem to reflect the structure of the Java application. If you have one `getSecurityLevel` method I would expect the same in the verification application, whichever language is used.

---

Otherwise, yes, it is a very simple proof of work. I'd rather require a *few* hashes instead of one, to average out the amount of work performed. With just one hash there will be a lot of luck involved, and the actual work will therefore vary rather wildly.

In the unlikely case that you've invented yet another popular PoW: I'd use 128 bits rather than a 64 bit long. It's pretty easy to make a counter that operates on bytes directly, so you would not even have to convert to the binary values required for the hashing.

Comment: Wow, you make great points! I've already switched to bit instead of byte "resolution" (but didn't update the post yet) - still using a loop to check though. Your explanations are very clear, but one recommendation I do not understand is the 128bit counter. I mean 64bit is already fairly large, so what's up with that?

Comment: Sure but the current bitcoin is using 68 THps (!). So yeah, if you just need it for your personal scheme then this proof of work can do with 64 bits; a general computer won't ever count to that I suppose. Cryptographers just don't like anything below 2^128 ;)

Comment: @Minding you must not update your post after receiving a review.

Comment: @mickmackusa Thanks for the info! Is it a hard rule I can read somewhere or more of a behaviour that is expected by the community?

Comment: https://codereview.meta.stackexchange.com/q/1763/141885